# Method call to bind a bean parameter

Tags: oracle-adf

A manage bean is configured in a bounded task flow as pageflow scope and in that taskflow I have a method call.The method needs a string as input and I wanna bind the value with a parameter in the  bean.
While doing that i.e making the EL I cannot find any bean in ADF Manage Bean. 
I have tried with different scope like request,backing bean,session,etc but none works.
Any solution u can suggest???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you register the bean with the adfc-config.xml unbounded task flow, then you will be able to see it in the EL editor for the parameter in the Bounded task flow.
However, the EL should still work if that bean is registered in the bounded task flow, it just isn't visible in the EL editor. You'll have to type the EL:

```
#{pageFlowScope.BeanName.attribute}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe , when i type the EL i can find it ,its just that it isn't visible in the EL editor .